# python: bs4 find/select parent tag but missing children inside

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

**Problem:**

I tried to use bs4 findAll and css selector to find the element, but I only got the parent tag with no children inside.

**What I have done:**

```
url = "https://my_url_to_scrap"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode("utf8"), "html5lib") # tried also with lxml, html.parser

lst_atc_href = soup.select("div.catalogentry")
lst_atc_href_2 = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "catalogentry"})
```

No matter lst_atc_href or lst_atc_href_2, I only got tag as follow:

```
[<div class="catalogentry" code="$$$ROOT$$$">
<div class="catalogentry-children"></div></div>]
```

All the children `<div class="catalogentry" code="A">` from A to V are missing.

Here is the html part from the web site:

```
<div class="catalogentry" code="$$$ROOT$$$">
    <div class="catalogentry-children">
      <div class="catalogentry" code="A">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="B">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="C">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="D">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="G">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="H">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="J">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="L">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="M">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="N">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="P">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="R">
         ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="S">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="catalogentry" code="V">
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Question:**

Is it because the missing content is generated by javascript ?
Could we scrape these missing content with only request (without selenium)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because the missing content is generated by javascript ? Could we scrape these missing content with only request (without selenium)?

Yes, it is. Just scrape the ajax API, and you will find the result:

```
import requests

response = requests.post('https://www.url_to_api.de/atc/children')
for element in response.json():
    print(element["code"], element["name"])
```

```
A Alimentäres System und Stoffwechsel
B Blut und blutbildende Organe
C Kardiovaskuläres System
D Dermatika
G Urogenitalsystem und Sexualhormone
H Systemische Hormonpräparate, exkl. Sexualhormone und Insuline
J Antiinfektiva zur systemischen Anwendung
L Antineoplastische und immunmodulierende Mittel
M Muskel- und Skelettsystem
N Nervensystem
P Antiparasitäre Mittel, Insektizide und Repellenzien
R Respirationstrakt
S Sinnesorgane
V Varia
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I would like to know if all the dynamic content which generated by js would always return the ajax API like this under the network?

Comment: @Mapotofu If content was generated by ajax, you could find API under network...... But not all content was generated by ajax in some cases.